# Can anyone tell me how can I remove this side line number and all blue color written from the CVPR paper overleaf template?

Tags: latex, overleaf

can anyone tell me how can I remove these blue line numbers and words? check the screenshot;

[image]

How can I remove this?

[image]

I have attached link of its template as well;

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/cvpr-2022-author-kit/qbmjsdxryffn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you neither want line numbers, nor the blue header, just don't use the `review` option:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}

%%%%%%%%% PAPER TYPE  - PLEASE UPDATE FOR FINAL VERSION
\usepackage[
%review
]{cvpr}      % To produce the REVIEW version

%%%%%%%%% PAPER ID  - PLEASE UPDATE
\def\cvprPaperID{*****} % *** Enter the CVPR Paper ID here
\def\confName{CVPR}
\def\confYear{2022}

\def\cvprruler#1{}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Can you tell me how can I remove the upper blue words, I am attaching the screen shot in the above question.